# airline reservation system in c

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2015, switch-statement, structure

Im trying to create an airline reservation system, which shoulw reserve a ticket, display the reserved ticket, and do the cancelation of ticket.I have written the code, using array structures. For now the code is only executing the reserve ticket and exit.

But when I press 1 for reserve ticket, it accepts the option but gives an error "Exception thrown at 0x0FFAFBB3 (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0004B000."

The code is stated below. Can anyone identify the error area in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize();
void reserve(); 

struct passengers {

char* firstname;    
char* surname;
char* passport;
};

passengers passenger[10]; 


void initialize()
{
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {

    passenger[a].passport = "";
    passenger[a].firstname = "";
    passenger[a].surname = "";

 }

 }
 void pause()
 {
printf("\n");
system("pause");
system("cls");
}


int main()  {

int seat = 0;

initialize();

int choice;

do {
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\t\t*************************************\n\n");
    printf("\t  *****Welcome To airline reservation system*****\n\n"); 
    printf("\t\t\t   ******************");
    printf("\n\n\t\t  1. RESERVE SEAT");
    printf("\n\n\t\t  2. CANCEL SEAT");
    printf("\n\n\t\t  3. DISPLAY SEAT LAYOUT");
    printf("\n\n\t\t  4. EXIT SYSTEM");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice); fflush(stdin);


    switch (choice) {

    case 1: reserve();
        break;
    case 2: cancel();
        break;
    case 3: display();
        break;
    case 4: exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nInvalid Choice");
    }

 } while (choice != 4);



_getch(); 

 }


 void reserve()   
{
int seat = 0;
passenger[seat].firstname = (char*)malloc(15);
passenger[seat].surname = (char*)malloc(15);
passenger[seat].passport = (char*)malloc(9);

for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)   
{

    if (passenger[a].passport == "")
    {
        seat = a; 
        break;
    }


}

if (seat < 10)
{
    printf("\n\t\t Enter First Name:");
    scanf_s("%s", passenger[seat].firstname);

    printf("\n\t\t Enter Surname:");
    scanf_s("%s", passenger[seat].surname);

    printf("\n\t\t Enter Passport Number:");
    scanf_s("%s", passenger[seat].passport);


}
else {

    printf("\n\t\t Sorry, No seats are available");


}

pause();

}
```

Comment: First, can we assume you're compiling this with something resembling a C++ compiler, because if not, `passengers passenger[10];` shouldn't compile, much less link and run. And you seem to have forgotten the `{` after `main()`, which again, would prevent this from compiling. Regarding your exceptions, you allocate no space for the string reads, so doing that invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `passengers passenger[10];` should be `struct passengers passenger[10];` Rewrite the whole thing, please. That's just too much of a mess!

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to debug the problem for yourself.

Comment: @WhozCraig how should i allocate space for strings in this?

Comment: There are *many* things wrong in this code, assuming the things already mentioned are fixed. String comparison isn't done right, and that `for (int a = 0; a >= 10; a++)` stands no chance of ever iterating, so `seat` will always be `0`. A debugger was *made* for things like this, and it appears you have one of the best at your disposal (visual studio has arguably the best debugger on Windows for user-programs; use it).

Comment: @Bonzi Reviewing the section in your book/tutorial on dynamic memory allocation would be the place to learn that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many problems, these should help. But you might need to fix issues that others are highlighting:

1. scanf_s should be passed size parameter for the %s , you are using it as if you are using scanf and not scanf_s see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx
2. You are not allocating space for your strings using malloc() or other means. So when scanf_s will attempt to write entered value it will be stomping on whatever the variables are pointing to. Which I presume isn't writable memory.
3. You are referring to the address of the pointer field in your structure instead of allocating memory to that pointer and passing the value in that pointer field:

   - Allocate:
     passenger[seat].firstname=(char*)malloc(MAX_FIRSTNAME_SIZE);
   - Change:
     '&passenger[seat].firstname' to 'passenger[seat].firstname'

Also (pardon me if I got this wrong) it looks like a term end project or a test question. Regardless of how unwanted this advice is: I would advise that you check out some documentation on setting breakpoints and using the visual studio debugger. Even just running the project in debug mode would take you right to the location where the error happens. This would help you learn the skill better and save you valuable time if you ever need to do this in a test.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have made the changes as stated by you. As i am in the learning phase of many things, your advices are surely informative. 
By making all the changes, after running the program, when I press the first option, it is displaying "enter first name". When i do enter, it gives me this error "Exception thrown at 0x0FFAFBB3 (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0004B000."

Comment: Your malloc calls need to be after you've picked the value for 'seat', I.e. in the beginning of the 'if (seat < 10)' block.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a passenger[10] array, so the valid indexes into this array are from 0..9. However, your for loop in the initialize() function also tries to initialize using index 10 (a <= 10), which is beyond the end of your array, which will be corrupting memory. As well, in your reserve() function, your for loop condition is wrong, you have 'a >= 10', I think you meant to use 'a < 10'.

Comment: Yes. I meant to use a<10. Ive corrected it already. Right now, working on the memory allocation for the strings that i have declared. Thank you